# Post method not execute using RestSharp in webAPI asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

```
var request = new RestRequest("controller", Method.POST);
                    request.AddJsonBody(object);
                    client.Execute(request);
```

`"controller"` is controllerName which derive from `ApiController`, `client` is localhost api address, `object` is data to pass.

controller method:

```
public void Post(object obj)
{
}
```

Comment: What is the type of response that you are getting? If it's a 404 then I'd guess that the problem is that the Web Api Routing isn't able to match the request.

Comment: No, its not 404, In this controller Get,Get by id, Put or Delete method work fine but only problem with Post method. No code break or 404 but after execute client request next line code execution start.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add
 request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;